# Convert date string from ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ ) to 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm`

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string date `2020-06-21T10:15:00Z`  into `21-06-2020 10:15`?

I did it like splitting on two parts and remove last 4 characters from the time:

```
 const newDate = date.split('T');
 const time = newDate.length >= 1 ? newDate[1].slice(3, -1) : '';
```

I am looking for some better solution?

Comment: try [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: To avoid messing up with timezones and date formats, you may simply [break your input string into parts and rearrange them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653630/11299053).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your input string has all the necessary parts, you may break it into pieces (e.g. using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and build up anew in desired order and with necessary delimiters:

```js
const dateStr = '2020-06-21T10:15:00Z',
      
      [yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mi] = dateStr.split(/[/:\-T]/)
      
console.log(`${dd}-${mm}-${yyyy} ${hh}:${mi}`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: much cleaner way!

Comment: Nice way of solving.

Answer (score 2):

You can format a

```js
const str = "2020-06-21T10:15:00Z";
const date = new Date(str);

var options = {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'};

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('UTC', options));
```

date string using `toLocaleDateString`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this one gets 2 upvotes as what live-snippet returns (`'6/21/2020, 1:15 PM'`) is not even close to what was requested (`'21-06-2020 10:15'`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var oldDate = Date.parse("2020-06-21T10:15:00Z");
  var newDate = formatDate(new Date(d));
  console.log(newDate)
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
        hour = d.getHours();
        minutes = d.getMinutes();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-') + " " + [hour,minutes].join(":");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :)

```
document.getElementById(' ').innerHTML = datum.toLocaleString('de-DE');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dateFormat](http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js)

```
const mydate = new Date("2020-06-21T10:15:00Z");
console.log(dateFormat(mydate, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM"));
```